# Scrapy python - I keep getting Crawled 0 pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have tried to follow multiple tutorials but no matter what I try I'm always getting the same result "Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)"

my code is very simple:

```
import scrapy

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

the output is:

> 2020-11-03 22:11:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.0 started
> (bot: books) 2020-11-03 22:11:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions:
> lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib
> 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) - [Clang 10.0.0 ], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
> 2020-11-03 22:11:52 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor:
> twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'books',
> 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'books.spiders',  'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
> 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['books.spiders']} 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: ae1669f089ac9e66
> 2020-11-03 22:11:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
> 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
> 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
> 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2020-11-03
> 22:11:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2020-11-03
> 22:11:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
> scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2020-11-03 22:11:52
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6023 2020-11-03 22:11:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET [http://books.toscrape.com/robots.txt>](http://books.toscrape.com/robots.txt%3E) (referer: None)
> 2020-11-03 22:11:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> [http://books.toscrape.com//>](http://books.toscrape.com//%3E) (referer: None)
> http://books.toscrape.com// 2020-11-03 22:11:53 [scrapy.core.engine]
> INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2020-11-03 22:11:53
> [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
> {'downloader/request_bytes': 455,  'downloader/request_count': 2,
> 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
> 'downloader/response_bytes': 6065,  'downloader/response_count': 2,
> 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
> 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,  'elapsed_time_seconds':
> 0.593427,  'finish_reason': 'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 3, 22, 11, 53, 534397),
> 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,  'log_count/INFO': 10,  'memusage/max':
> 49852416,  'memusage/startup': 49852416,  'response_received_count':
> 2,  'robotstxt/request_count': 1,  'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
> 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,  'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
> 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,  'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
> 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020,
> 11, 3, 22, 11, 52, 940970)} 2020-11-03 22:11:53 [scrapy.core.engine]
> INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output shows that you have crawled two pages:

```
http://books.toscrape.com/robots.txt (HTTP status 404 error)
http://books.toscrape.com// (HTTP status 200)
```

It looks like everything works (except I don't see you `print` statement in your outout).

Comment: Thank you, I was expecting the crawl to say that I crawled at least 1 page so when I saw the output saying it was 0 I just assumed it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no robots.txt on the site you're scraping.

You can disable obeying robots.txt by going to the settings.py of scrapy and find ROBOTSTXT_OBEY. Set this to false.

Comment: I tried this but it hasn't fixed the issue... still getting the same thing